# How to telecast a live streaming video on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I need to telecast to a group of friends a video with live streaming specifically to YouTube. Are there any ways to accomplish this?

Can you suggest me some methods or tools to stream live on YouTube?

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need a Google+ Account for that.

According to the Google blog [post](http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/google-hangouts-on-air-broadcast-your.html), users can broadcast their live hangout to their Google+ stream, but also to their YouTube channel or their website. It’s those last two items, and primarily the option to broadcast live to [YouTube/live](http://YouTube.com/live) as well as Google+ that makes the general availability of [Hangouts On Air](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html) so interesting.

*Hangouts On Air* uses a combination of Google+ and YouTube Live to let you engage with even more people, while YouTube Live focuses more on broadcasting an event to your audience. For example, you’d watch your favorite band play on YouTube Live but then engage with them backstage in a *Hangout On Air*.